angular router don't work for some urls after built and deployed
I am having a problem with my angular router after built and deployed, some of the url don't work, and "cannot get" shows. Locally it works fine and all url response with the respective component, but after I execute ng build and then paste the compiled folder inside my backend project with node and use it with express and it's static method, some url work good but some others just respond with "cannot ge". my repo is in https://github.com/josecabrera28/stateflow_Back
I tried building and pasting the compiled folder inside my backend project and use the static files with app.use(express.static("stateflow-front")); I also tried to build it and deploy it separately from the backend in a different web-service with render,but same problem and with the same urls.
